# replace img src with jquery on click

Tags: jquery, image, load, fadein, removeclass

This might seem as child play, but I can't figure out how I can replace the src attribute of an image.

The src is "build.php" which generate the image. What I want is when I click on "mix" it will run build.php to generate a new image, remove the old image and display the new image with a nice fadeout/fadein.

Also with an "Building new image" which hides when the new image is done loading.

I tried with

```
$("#mix").click(function(){
   var img = new Image();
      $(img).load(function () {
         $(this).hide();
         $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
         $(this).fadeIn();
   }).attr('src', 'build.php');
});
```

But the 2nd time I click on "mix" it will place new image under the old image, not remove the old image.

Comment: Is it still reproduce when you clear browser cache after each click on image?

Comment: @InviS - #mix is the anchor (<a href="#" id="mix">Mix</div>)

Comment: And where image (you want to replace) is? if `#mix` is an anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#mix").click(function(){
       var img = new Image();
          $(img).load(function () {
             $(this).hide();
             $('#loader').removeClass('loading').append(this);
             $(this).fadeIn();
       }).attr('src','').attr('src', 'build.php');
    });
```

Look below - works :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#yourimagediv").click(function() {
$("#yourimagediv").attr("src","image.php?"+new Date().getTime());
});
});​
```

```html
<img id="yourimagediv" src="image.php" />
```

Comment: It still places the new image below the old.

Comment: What id or class has the img tag that holds the picture?

Comment: Look at my edit. Change #yourimagediv to #brick-image.
and image.php to build.php.

I improved mine as well with the answer above mine by inviS

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mix = $('#mix'),
    jqImage = $('#brick-image');

mix.on('click', function (e) {
    var img = new Image();
    jqImage.fadeOut();
    img.onload = function () {
      jqImage.attr('src', img.src);
      jqImage.fadeIn();
    };
    // add param to prevent caching of build.php image
    img.src = 'build.php?' + new Date().getTime();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```