# replacing img and keeping link to the change function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do two things on click on the image: (i) to replace src attribute of that image; and (ii) keep the link to the function doing (i). My code below works only for the first click but not any more clicks on the image:

javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $('.link_check_allowed').click(function(){
        $('#check_allowed').removeClass("link_check_allowed");
        $('#check_allowed').prop("class", "link_check_not_allowed");
        $('#check_allowed_image').prop("src", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/4/1/a/1195429270821624493molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_4.svg.med.png");
    });

    $('.link_check_not_allowed').click(function(){
        $('#check_allowed').removeClass("link_check_not_allowed");
        $('#check_allowed').prop("class", "link_check_allowed");
        $('#check_allowed_image').prop("src", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/8/2/2/1195423990759977006molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_5.svg.med.png");
    });

 });
```

html:

```
<a style='border:0; cursor:pointer'>
    <div id='check_allowed' class='link_check_allowed'>
       <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/8/2/2/1195423990759977006molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_5.svg.med.png" width="50" height="50" border="0" id="check_allowed_image"/>
     </div>
</a>
```

I have tried an advise described here: [replace img src with jquery on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476646/replace-img-src-with-jquery-on-click) but it did not help.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M63QY/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the events are bound while there are no elements on the page with the class of `.link_check_not_allowed`. Given that, I'd suggest changing your jQuery to the following:

```
$('.link_check_allowed').on('click', function(){
    $('#check_allowed').toggleClass('link_check_allowed link_check_not_allowed');
    $('#check_allowed_image').prop('src', function(i,src){
        return src == 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/4/1/a/1195429270821624493molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_4.svg.med.png' ? 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/8/2/2/1195423990759977006molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_5.svg.med.png' : 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/4/1/a/1195429270821624493molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_4.svg.med.png';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M63QY/9/).

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

you can look into using .toggle() on the src of the image.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-options

Comment: The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9. Avoid using it

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Live" Event like

```
  $("#check_allowed").on("click",function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("link_check_allowed"))
   {
    $('#check_allowed').removeClass("link_check_allowed").addClass("link_check_not_allowed").prop("src", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/4/1/a/1195429270821624493molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_4.svg.med.png");
   }
  if($(this).hasClass("link_check_not_allowed"))
   {
    $('#check_allowed').removeClass("link_check_not_allowed").addClass("link_check_allowed")prop("src", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/8/2/2/1195423990759977006molumen_multicolor_power_buttons_5.svg.med.png");
   }
 });
```

it will work.

Comment: `live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and you should start phasing out its use in your code.

Comment: As @RAJ... said, you should most definitely **not** use `.live`. Remember, stack overflow is for not only the OP but also all other visitors. You should edit your answer to instead use `.on`, so as to not perpetuate the use of deprecated features.